# DataContract IsReference=true returning empty objects

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, wcf

I have a WCF service with cyclic references that I was using the CyclicReferencesAwareAttribute attribute (http://chabster.blogspot.com/2008/02/wcf-cyclic-references-support.html) to solve. However now I want to use the same service with a Silverlight client. Receiving data works well on the Silverlight client with this method, however the CyclicReferencesAwareAttribute attribute does not work on the Silverlight side when I want to send objects back again.

I have changed to use the IsReference property on the data contract which is supposed to get round with this issue. However now the objects that are returned are empty! (All fields are either default or null). This is the same in my ASP.NET client (original) and my Silverlight client.

Has anyone hit is issue before? Here is the attribute.
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract(Namespace="http://testnamespace.co.uk/entities", IsReference=true)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- Make sure that all the properties have the System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember attribute.

2- Make sure that all properties that need to be transfered have a public getter and setter

Comment: I hadnt added DataMember attributes to all the properties, mainly because its an EntityFramework POCO. I will do this and see how it ends up.

Comment: Yes, I had to add DataMember attributes to my POCO T4. This now works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me too.  Unfortunately this isn't a little more seamless.  If there is a way to do this without adding a bunch of attributes to properties manually I'd like to know.